# DispatchQueue загрузка изображений

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Не могу разобраться с многопоточностью.
Изображения получаю из сети с помощью URLSession, естественно интерфейс загружается раньше чем подгружаются картинки. Понимаю что нужно использовать `DispatchQueue.main.async { }`, но не могу сообразить какую часть кода заключить в скобки  (если стороку `imgData = data`, то это не дает результата). Нашел способ через `sleep(1)`, но это настоящий костыль который тормозит приложение.

```
func getImage(url: String) -> Image {
    var imgData = Data()
    
    if let parsedURL = URL(string: url) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: parsedURL) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data {
                imgData = data
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    
    sleep(1)
    
    if let image = UIImage(data: imgData) {
        return Image(uiImage: image)
    } else {
        return Image(systemName: "photo")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Можно добавить параметр для возврата замыкания, поскольку результат возвращается асинхронно</strike>

```
    func getImage(url: String, completion: @escaping (Image) -> Void) {
        var imgData = Data()
        
        if let parsedURL = URL(string: url) {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: parsedURL) { data, response, error in
                if let data = data {
                    imgData = data
                    
                    if let image = UIImage(data: imgData) {
                        completion(Image(uiImage: image))
                    } else {
                        completion(Image(systemName: "photo"))
                    }
                }
            }.resume()
        }
    }
```

**Дополнение**

Для SwiftUI вышеуказанный код не подойдет, все будет несколько сложнее, вот пример, взятый [отсюда](https://www.vadimbulavin.com/asynchronous-swiftui-image-loading-from-url-with-combine-and-swift/)

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class ImageLoader: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var image: UIImage?
    private let url: URL
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    
    init(url: URL) {
        self.url = url
    }
    
    deinit {
        cancellable?.cancel()
    }
    
    func load() {
        cancellable = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .map { UIImage(data: $0.data) }
            .replaceError(with: nil)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .assign(to: \.image, on: self)
    }
    
    func cancel() {
        cancellable?.cancel()
    }
}


struct AsyncImage<Placeholder: View>: View {
    
    @ObservedObject private var loader: ImageLoader
    private let placeholder: Placeholder?
    
    init(url: URL, placeholder: Placeholder? = nil) {
        loader = ImageLoader(url: url)
        self.placeholder = placeholder
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        image
            .onAppear(perform: loader.load)
            .onDisappear(perform: loader.cancel)
    }
    
    private var image: some View {
        Group {
            if loader.image != nil {
                Image(uiImage: loader.image!)
                    .resizable()
            } else {
                placeholder
            }
        }
    }
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var urlString: String
    
    var body: some View {
        
        if urlString != "" {
            AsyncImage(
                url: URL(string: urlString)!,
                placeholder: Text("Loading ...")
            ).aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: А как вызывать такую [функцию?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hhuwq.png)

Comment: @sumrakss см дополнение